# What variant of Linux AMI is provided by Amazon

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

We used the http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/ to create a EC2 instance with the following info

Linux ip-10-322-36-29 3.6.45.21-99.3.amzn1.i686 #1 SMP Sat Feb 19 3:11:26
UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

What variant of Linux, am I using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Amazon Linux AMI distribution is homebrew by Amazon and is based on RHEL 5.x and parts of RHEL6.

source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=194752